# Route HTTP(S) traffic to specific IP based on requested URL on Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, routing, http

I have an Ubuntu Server in the cloud. Let's call it *ServerA*.
*ServerA* has an apache2 installed and is serving a default page on HTTP requests. `mydomain.com` is pointing to the *ServerA*'s IP and thus the default *ServerA*'s site is available via this domain name as well.

*ServerA* has an OpenVPN installed and works as a VPN gateway for different clients to connect.

When *ServerB* connects to *ServerA* as an OpenVPN client, it is assigned a local IP in the OpenVPN network that *ServerA*'s OpenVPN has created.

I set `myotherdoamin.com` to point to the same *ServerA*'s IP. I would like *ServerA* to be configured that way so that if an HTTP request to `mydomain.com` comes in - it is routed to *ServerA*'s apache2 and the local site is served. In case a request to `myotherdomain.com` comes in, I would like *ServerA* to route the request to a connected *ServerB*'s HTTP port, thus returning a VPN client's HTTP response.

My questions are:

1. Is iptables capable fo routing rules based on HTTP request headers?
2. Is apache2 capable to routing requests to other IP's based on HTTP request headers?
3. Which application is best for handling my desired behavior?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is iptables capable of routing rules based on HTTP request headers?

No, it's not. IPTables works at layer 3/4, and HTTP request headers are layer 7.

> Is apache2 capable to routing requests to other IP's based on HTTP request headers?

Yes, using [mod_proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mod_proxy), Apache can proxy those requests to another server.

> Which application is best for handling my desired behavior?

As stated above, mod_proxy will work for you, but any other reverse proxy that can operate at layer 7 will do the trick. Along with Apache's mod_proxy, Nginx and HAproxy are probably the most common ones.